# Second declension feminine plants

Tags: noun, gender, second-declension

Is there any reason why some well-known plant names, especially tree names, are feminine, but 2nd declension? (now interested in classical, not scientific ones). For example:

- Trees:

  - [aesculus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=aesculus)
  - [alnus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=alnus)
  - [balanus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=balanus)
  - [buxus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=buxus)
  - [corylus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=corylus)
  - [cerasus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=cerasus)
  - [cedrus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=cedrus)
  - [citrus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=citrus)
  - [cornus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=cornus)
  - ...
  - [fāgus , i](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=fagus) (but nom. pl. fagūs,)
  - ...
- Herbs:

  - [acinos](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=acinos)
  - [intybus](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=intybus)
  - ...

Comment: You might find this useful https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7353/39

Comment: and you might learn something from https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/7017/39

Comment: I hope someone else will answer this very interesting question. Meanwhile, a somewhat cryptic note from Weiss 2020, "In Greek and Latin, tree and plant names are regularly feminine, probably preserving an old pattern" (p. 243).

Comment: @AlexB. it doesn't seem like this question is going to get an answer :( Do you think you could post one based on the points you've made above?

Comment: A related wordreference thread: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/gendering-trees.3361383/

Comment: Also see https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10939/39

Comment: Grosheva 2005 (Грошева 2005) *Индоевропейское наследие в латинских названиях деревьев*, in *Hrda manasa*, pp. 252-272. This is a festschrift in honor of L.G. Herzenberg, a famous Russian linguist.

Comment: @double-beep short answer: we don’t know. I might summarize some relevant info some time later, when I have free time

Comment: I don't know either, but I wonder whether there is some conflation between these nouns and the feminine noun *arbor*, meaning "tree".

Answer (score 1):

It is the principle of feminine, that gives birth. Not all plants are feminine, but e.g. trees are, while fruit is in general neuter. E.g. malus, -i, f.  (apple tree) and malum, -i, n. (apple). Not all are second declension, like quercus, -us, f.  or ilex, -icis, f.
In Latin, except for many plants, feminine are also for the same reason earth and parts, like islands and states - Sicilia, Sardinia, Hispania,Gallia, Italia, Illyria ... on the other side masculine is what fertilize, like winds, that carry semen, rivers, parts of great Oceanus that embraces the Earth like man does to a woman...
Also, when they come from Greek, it could be feminine because it was feminine in Greek... not only connected with plant names e.g. dialectus, -i, f.

Comment: I just noticed that all edible-fruit-bearing trees and shrubs that are native to temperate Europe are feminine in Polish, with exception of _orzech_ "walnut" (not exactly a typical fruit) and _agrest_ "gooseberry" (a loan from Latin, so it probably doesn't count; also, it has multiple native synonyms that are feminine, like _kosmatka_).  So there might be something to it.